# Como informar uma variável, associada a uma linha de um campo da tabela, para uma template

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando montar uma lista de links que apontem para uma template, onde uma das variáveis, com o conteúdo de um dos campos da tabela, deve ser informada dinamicamente na template (estando associada a uma linha específica da tabela).

O código que gera a lista:

```
require_once("conexao.php"); 

$sql = "SELECT `username`, `userid` FROM `banco` WHERE username='$user_name'"; // aqui ele pega o username do usuário logado pra gerar a lista buscando no BD

$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) { //alguns dados
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<br>Nome: ' . $dados['username'] . ' ';
    echo 'ID: ' . $dados['userid'] . ' ' <br><br>';

// e aqui é pra gerar a lista de links pra essa template
    echo " 

    <a href='template.php'>Ir para a template e informar qual linha deve ser pega na variável  </a>

    ";
    echo '</div>';
}
```

O campo que quero pegar é gerado assim:

```
// BASE
ob_start();
include "../saida.php";
$output = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('filename', $output);
echo $output;
?>
```

Daí tenho o SQL que grava esse dado no banco, num campo `text long`, e até aí tudo certo...

Na página da template o código está assim:

```
require_once("conexao.php"); 
    $sql = "SELECT `campo` FROM `banco` WHERE username='$user_name'";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo  utf8_encode($dados['campo']);
                        }
```

Assim ele pega todos os resultados, e retorna todos os conteúdos deste  campo da tabela associado ao usuário logado, e escreve um resultado abaixo do outro... agora queria gerar uma lista de links, e gerar uma template pra trazer o conteúdo de cada linha específica da tabela, com o campo  associado à linha da tabela que gerou o link. (ah, tomara que não esteja ficando ainda mais confuso :P)...

Pensei que seria o caso de criar um `for`ou `foreach` pra gerar esta variável dinamicamente, e informar a linha da tabela a ser pega (via URL?) na página da template, mas não sei se é o ideal, não sei como fazer isso, tô bem confuso por aqui... :) :/

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, em `template.php` vc quer receber/acessar a variável `$dados`?

Comment: Sim, mas associada a linha correta da tabela. Acho que ficou confuso porque tirei a parte do `while`na página da template, o `$dados['campo']`ficou sem sentido... É que na página da template, se coloco com o `while` assim `while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo  utf8_encode($dados['campo']);
                        }` ele retorna todos os resultados, um abaixo do outro. Mas eu preciso que estes links (em outra página) apontem cada um pra uma linha... por isso tirei o while, mas acho que acabei confundindo mais do que explicando... vou editar... valeu.

Comment: @rray editei, vê se dá pra entender... é que eu gravo essas infos de um formulário, e quero colocar o conteúdo de um dos campos (um trecho de código HTML) da tabela numa template... pra cada vez que usuário responde o formulário gera uma linha da tabela, então estes links são montados com cada linha, e a template precisa pegar o conteúdo da linha específica... Na verdade deve ser algo simples, eu que to me embanando pra explicar :) :/

Comment: Editei mais um pouco incluindo como gravo essa variável e incluo este campo na tabela... @rray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se é a forma mais segura, porque to passando um parâmetro pela URL, mas consegui resolver assim:

1 - Criei um campo no BD com auto incremento;

```
ALTER TABLE  tabela ADD  `idautoinc` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `idautoinc` ) ;
```

2 - Mudei o `SELECT` para incluir este campo:

```
$sql = "SELECT `diagravacao`, `idautoinc` FROM `tabela` WHERE username='$user_name' ORDER BY `diagravacao` DESC";
```

3 -  Mudei o `while` para:

```
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<div id="resultsbd">';
    echo '<br><b>Data:</b> ' . $dados['diagravacao'] . ' &nbsp &nbsp';
    echo '<b>Id do campo com autoincremento:</b>' . $dados['idautoinc'] . '<br><br>'; 
}
```

4 - Criei uma variável pra pegar esse id:

```
 $idautoinc = $dados['idautoinc'];
```

5 - E agora passo o número do campo com autoincremento pela URL, assim:

```
<a href='template.php?idautoinc=$idautoinc'></a>
```

6 - Então pego o campo:

```
$idAutoInc = $_GET['idautoinc'];
```

7 - E agora consigo consultar o campo específico, assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT `campo` FROM `tabela` WHERE username='$user_name' AND idcalc='$idautoinc'";
```

8 - E assim cada link pega o `id` do campo correto:

```
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo  utf8_encode($dados['campo']);
    }
```

Comment: Legal que conseguiu resolver :). Não se isso se aplica ao caso, trocar chaamada do link por um `include` ai vc já aproveita `$dados` so precisa fazer um verificação em `$idAutoInc`.

Comment: Faço o include da página que faz a lista na página de resultado? Ah, claro, saquei... é mais seguro? é mais rápido (porque ele vai ter que ler a página toda né)? é outra pergunta? :) @rray

Comment: Um pouco mais por não expor o id, mas vantagem é compartilhar `$dados` mesmo.

Comment: Legal, valeu @rray... abraço!